# fetch data from json array

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

please see this URL: "http://www.zaferteam.com/wp-json/posts/" .
 it's json array of my website posts.
 i want to store each member of this array in posts array.
 at last in posts array will be all posts of my website in json format.
 at the end of the code i try to get the ID of each post.
 my posts ID are in-order: 34  32  20  24 
 but it shows: 24  24  24  24
 please help me, thanks.

```
$(
function(){ 
//api start 
var URL = "http://www.zaferteam.com/wp-json/posts/";
//for storing feteched posts
var FetchedPost = {
    //----Start wordpress fields----
    ID:"",
    title:"",
    status:"",
    type:"",
    author:{
        ID:"",
        username:"",
        name:"",
        first_name:"",
        last_name:"",
        nickname:"",
        slug:"",
        URL:"",
        avatar:"",
        description:"",
        registered:"",
        meta:{
        linkss:{self:"", 
            archives:""
                }
            }
        },
    content: "",
    parent: "",
    links: "",
    date: "",
    modified: "",
    format: "",
    slug: "",
    guid: "",
    excerpt: "",
    menu_order: "",
    comment_status: "",
    ping_status: "",
    sticky: "",
    date_tz: "",
    date_gmt: "",
    modified_tz: "",
    modified_gmt: "",
    meta:{
        linkss:{self: "", author: ""}
        },
    featured_image:{
        ID: "", title: "", status: "", guid:""
        },
    terms:{
        category:[
                {
                ID:"",
                name:"",
                slug:"",
                description: "",
                taxonomy: "",
                parent: "",
                count: "",
                links: "",
                meta:{
                    linkss:{collection: ""}
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
//----End wordpress fields----

//methods for fetching data from a post . [input parameter is a post]
var methods ={
//get ID of the post
    ID:function(post){
        FetchedPost.ID = post.ID;
    },
//get title of the post 
    title:function(post){
        FetchedPost.title = post.title;
    },
//get ID of the author ID   
    authorID:function(post){
        FetchedPost.author.ID = post.author.ID;
    },

//get name of the author name   
    authorName:function(post){
        FetchedPost.author.name = post.author.name;
    },
//get username of the author username   
    authorUsername:function(post){
        FetchedPost.author.username = post.author.username;
    },  
//get title of the content  
    content:function(post){
        FetchedPost.content = post.content;
    },
//get links 
    links:function(post){
        FetchedPost.links = post.links;
    },
//get the featured_image guid (featured_image links) of the post
    featuredImageGuid:function(post){

        //alert(typeof post.featured_image.guid);
        if(post.featured_image != null){
        FetchedPost.featured_image.guid = post.featured_image.guid;
        }
        else{
            FetchedPost.featured_image.guid = "#";
            }
        //alert(typeof milad);
    }   
}

function wpMain(post){
    methods.ID(post);
    methods.title(post);
    methods.authorID(post);
    methods.authorName(post);
    methods.authorUsername(post);
    methods.content(post);
    methods.links(post);
    methods.featuredImageGuid(post);
    }  

//fetch by ajax
    $.ajax({
    url: URL,
    success: function(data, status) {
        var localData = JSON.stringify(data);
        window.localStorage.setItem('WPpost', localData);
    },
    error: function() {
        //handle the error
    }
    });
var localData = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem('WPpost'));
        var Length = localData.length;
        var posts = new Array();
        $.each(localData,function(index,value){
            wpMain(value);
            posts.push(FetchedPost);
            });

        $.each(posts,function(index,value){
            alert(value.ID);
            }); 
    });
```

Comment: Please explain your question more. What is  24 24 24 24?

Comment: it's the ID of each post

Comment: Again, please explain your question more. I don't get how you are arriving at 24 24 24 24 and how you know it should be 34 32 20 24.

Comment: @milad-ahmadi04 you should make jsfiddle or demo working code for this

Comment: please see this URL:

Comment: @milad-ahmadi04 Okay! why do you want it that way? as i can see you have got the response so can't you just store it in the localStorage directly, instead of creating an object and passing it in the function and so on which is a bit late while your loop ends.

Comment: have you checked whether correct data is getting saved in `localStorage` or not?

Comment: yes correct data saved in localStorage

Comment: @Ron the question edited

Comment: @HimeshAadeshara jsfiddle does't show reult because of the $.ajax() method i think

Comment: I agree with the other guys and suggest you handle the pushing of the data inside the success block. I don't see the need to save it to localStorage just to retrieve it again. But to help, try and clear your FetchedPost after every push. Maybe there is some inconsistency when it is getting saved via wpMain.

Comment: @Jai what is your suggestion? can you code it plaese?

Comment: Oh ok, just wanted to check, why `var localData = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem('WPpost'));` and the subsequent code is not written inside Ajax `success` handler?

Comment: @Ron i tested it before. but i had same problem.

Comment: @vijayP : i want to have the result out of the success handler for next modifies

Comment: @milad-ahmadi04 - i will suggest to put `var localData = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem('WPpost'));` and the subsequent code in newer function lets say `function readLocalStorageData()` and call it from `success:` handler after `window.localStorage.setItem('WPpost', localData);` line. See what you get.

Comment: i think you are pushing the same object instances into your posts array. so all of your objects in the array same like the last entry. you could try to "clone" your FetchedPost object before filling it..

Comment: @vijayP i can't handdle your suggestion. please code it the most direct way

Comment: @eaCe please explain it by codes

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This works fine with a local json file:

Added the test var...

```
var URL = "my.json";
var test;
//for storing feteched posts
var FetchedPost = {
    //----Start wordpress fields----
    ID: "",
    title: "",
    status: "",
    type: "",
    author: {
        ID: "",
        username: "",
        name: "",
        first_name: "",
        last_name: "",
        nickname: "",
        slug: "",
        URL: "",
        avatar: "",
        description: "",
        registered: "",
        meta: {
            linkss: {self: "",
                archives: ""
            }
        }
    },
    content: "",
    parent: "",
    links: "",
    date: "",
    modified: "",
    format: "",
    slug: "",
    guid: "",
    excerpt: "",
    menu_order: "",
    comment_status: "",
    ping_status: "",
    sticky: "",
    date_tz: "",
    date_gmt: "",
    modified_tz: "",
    modified_gmt: "",
    meta: {
        linkss: {self: "", author: ""}
    },
    featured_image: {
        ID: "", title: "", status: "", guid: ""
    },
    terms: {
        category: [
            {
                ID: "",
                name: "",
                slug: "",
                description: "",
                taxonomy: "",
                parent: "",
                count: "",
                links: "",
                meta: {
                    linkss: {collection: ""}
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
//----End wordpress fields----

//methods for fetching data from a post . [input parameter is a post]
var methods = {
//get ID of the post
    ID: function (post) {
        test.ID = post.ID;
    },
//get title of the post 
    title: function (post) {
        test.title = post.title;
    },
//get ID of the author ID   
    authorID: function (post) {
        test.author.ID = post.author.ID;
    },
//get name of the author name   
    authorName: function (post) {
        test.author.name = post.author.name;
    },
//get username of the author username   
    authorUsername: function (post) {
        test.author.username = post.author.username;
    },
//get title of the content  
    content: function (post) {
        test.content = post.content;
    },
//get links 
    links: function (post) {
        test.links = post.links;
    },
//get the featured_image guid (featured_image links) of the post
    featuredImageGuid: function (post) {

        //alert(typeof post.featured_image.guid);
        if (post.featured_image != null) {
            test.featured_image.guid = post.featured_image.guid;
        }
        else {
            test.featured_image.guid = "#";
        }
        //alert(typeof milad);
    }
}

function wpMain(post)
{
    test = jQuery.extend(true, {}, FetchedPost);
    methods.ID(post);
    methods.title(post);
    methods.authorID(post);
    methods.authorName(post);
    methods.authorUsername(post);
    methods.content(post);
    methods.links(post);
    methods.featuredImageGuid(post);
}

//fetch by ajax
$.ajax({
    url: URL,
    mimeType: "application/json",
    success: function (data, status) {
        var localData = JSON.stringify(data);
        window.localStorage.setItem('WPpost', localData);
    },
    error: function () {
        //handle the error
    }
});
var localData = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem('WPpost'));
var Length = localData.length;
var posts = new Array();
$.each(localData, function (index, value) {
    wpMain(value);
    posts.push(test);
});

$.each(posts, function (index, value) {
    console.log(value.ID);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try following approach:

create new function `function readLocalStorageData()` as follows:

```
function readLocalStorageData()
{
    var localData = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem('WPpost'));
    var Length = localData.length;
    var posts = new Array();
    $.each(localData,function(index,value){
        wpMain(value);
        posts.push(FetchedPost);
    });

    $.each(posts,function(index,value){
        alert(value.ID);
    }); 
}
```

now call above function your ajax `success` handler as follows:

```
//fetch by ajax
        $.ajax({
        url: URL,
        success: function(data, status) {
            var localData = JSON.stringify(data);
            window.localStorage.setItem('WPpost', localData);

            readLocalStorageData(); //read the locally stored data
        },
        error: function() {
            //handle the error
        }
    });
```

Comment: i tested your way. i have same problem. output: 24  24  24  24